# Power BI Slicer

Tags: powerbi

In Slicer  i want customized or dynamic value. For example, I have a field with 10 items. Now, my drop down should have value SELECT ALL (in this all 10 items will be included), SELECT ALL EXCLUDING (in this i want 7 out 10 items) and below this 7 items of my choice will be listed. I tried using group but its not working as expected.

Item : A B C D E F G H I J

In  SELECT ALL - A to J should be selected or included (showing selected is not required)

SELECT ALL EXCLUDING - A to G will be selected or included

The drop down value should be like this -

SELECT ALL,
SELECT ALL EXCLUDING,
A,
B,
C,
D,
E,
F,
G